# TimerTrigger on we bjob with .net core 2.2

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered

I am using Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs (3.0.8) and I am getting an error an compile time stating

```
listener for function 'Functions.ProcessCollateFiles' was unable to start.

Inner Exception 1:
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Arg_ParamName_Name
```

I am looking at the samples in the nuget documentation and I cannot see what is causing the issue.

My function is

```
public void ProcessCollateFiles([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * *", RunOnStartup = true)]TimerInfo timerInfo)
        {

               // _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "tester");

                Console.WriteLine("test");

        }
```

I have noticed that the null value is for a parameter of **connectionString**
I am not sure what this is used for with regards to the TimerTrigger though

Answer (score 2):

About your exception, you could follow this tutorial: [Configure storage to run locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started#configure-storage-to-run-locally) to set the `AzureWebJobsStorage` string. your json will be like the below shows.

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "{storage connection string}"
  }
}
```

The **AzureWebJobsStorage** connection string is **required** - while you might not be using any storage entities, the WebJobs runtime does use some blobs and other storage entities for its own tracking and operation.

And it is only required when using the WebJobs SDK, to use Azure WebJobs you don't have to use WebJobs SDK so you don't have to have `AzureWebJobsStorage` connection string.